# Java two-way parameterized class

Tags: java, generics, parameterized

Is it possible to do this in java without problems?
My IDE highlights my code as "Raw use of parameterized class 'Etat' " and "Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.ArrayList'"
My code :

```
public abstract class Etat<T extends Transition> {}
```

```
public abstract class Transition<E extends Etat> {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might you be looking for:

```
class Etat<E extends Etat<E, T>, T extends Transition<E, T>>  {}
class Transition<E extends Etat<E, T>, T extends Transition<E, T>> {}
```

Then, you can do:

```
class MonEtat extends Etat<MonEtat, MaTransition> {}
class MaTransition extends Transition<MonEtat, MaTransition> {}
```

allowing the two types to know each other through their type parameter. For instance, if you declare:

```
class Etat<E extends Etat<E, T>, T extends Transition<E, T>> {
    abstract E apply(T transition);
}
```

You can then be assured that

```
MonEtat e = ...;
e = e.apply(new MaTransition()); // compiles, and knows that MonEtat is returned
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is the solution to my problem.
Just on your first code block the parameters of the class are not in the same order as the third and the second.

Comment: Oops. Could have sworn I had fixed that, but I apparently I failed to copy it over from eclipse. Fixed now.